# Find in Python the fastest Id from file

Tags: python, average

I a file with name aaa.txt'
in this file I have this information :

```
19-3-2020 01:37:31.995  INFO    18  188 mailbox allocated for rsvp
19-3-2020 01:37:32.039  INFO    14  194 creating mailslot for dump
19-3-2020 01:37:32.082  INFO    18  194 out of INFO allcations
19-3-2020 01:37:32.119  INFO    18  188 creating mailslot for RSVP client API
19-3-2020 01:37:32.157  INFO    10  187 creating socket for traffic CONTROL module
19-3-2020 01:37:32.157  INFO    19  186 transaction 17327 begin
19-3-2020 01:37:32.276  INFO    11  188 loopback to avoid ERROR
19-3-2020 01:37:32.276  INFO    15  187 end transaction 17327
19-3-2020 01:37:32.314  INFO    13  189 creating mailslot for terminate
```

1. 1 Script : How can I found the ID of the fastest transaction?
2. 2 Script : get the average transaction in ms ?

Thank for all

Comment: which part is `ID`?

Comment: which part is `ID` and Which part is `transaction time`? can you show us your actual code what have you tried already?

Comment: ID - transaction ( XXX ) begin - end transaction ( XXX )

Time - e.g. if a transaction started at 07:15:10.100 and ended at 07:15:11.050 then is took 950 ms

Comment: I've edited my initial answer to reflect the comments that were made here

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment you gave on the questions I've increase the demo input text. I appended some extra data on the bottom, without all the lines in between. New input file:

```
19-3-2020 01:37:31.995  INFO    18  188 mailbox allocated for rsvp
19-3-2020 01:37:32.039  INFO    14  194 creating mailslot for dump
19-3-2020 01:37:32.082  INFO    18  194 out of INFO allcations
19-3-2020 01:37:32.119  INFO    18  188 creating mailslot for RSVP client API
19-3-2020 01:37:32.157  INFO    10  187 creating socket for traffic CONTROL module
19-3-2020 01:37:32.157  INFO    19  186 transaction 17327 begin
19-3-2020 01:37:32.276  INFO    11  188 loopback to avoid ERROR
19-3-2020 01:37:32.276  INFO    15  187 end transaction 17327
19-3-2020 01:37:32.314  INFO    13  189 creating mailslot for terminate
19-3-2020 01:37:32.157  INFO    19  186 transaction 17328 begin
19-3-2020 01:37:32.314  INFO    15  187 end transaction 17328
19-3-2020 01:37:32.120  INFO    19  186 transaction 17329 begin
19-3-2020 01:37:32.276  INFO    15  187 end transaction 17329
19-3-2020 01:37:32.250  INFO    19  186 transaction 17330 begin
19-3-2020 01:37:32.640  INFO    15  187 end transaction 17330
```

To get the shortest time between begin and end of transaction you have to loop through all the transactions and store when each started and when each ended. I've done this by storing it all in a `dict`, if you input is very large you might want to do this more optimally.

```py
import re
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict

transactions = defaultdict(dict)
# Parse File ans store times and ids in dictionary
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    all_lines = f.readlines()
    trans_regex = r'transaction\s(\d+)'
    time_regex = r'\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+'
    for line in all_lines:
        m = re.search(trans_regex, line)
        t = re.search(time_regex, line)

        time_str = t.group(0) 
        time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, '%H:%M:%S.%f')

        if m is not None:
        
            ID = m.group(1)
            if 'begin' in line:
                transactions[ID]['start'] = time
            if 'end' in line:
                transactions[ID]['end'] = time

            if 'end' in transactions[ID] and 'start' in transactions[ID]:
                delta_time = transactions[ID]['end'] - transactions[ID]['start']
                transactions[ID]['delta'] = delta_time.total_seconds() * 1000 # x1000 for milisecs

# After file read
min_time = float('inf')
min_id = None
total_time = 0
delta_count = 0
for ID, data in transactions.items():
    if 'delta' in data: 
        total_time = data['delta']
        delta_count += 1

        if data['delta'] < min_time:
            min_time = data['delta']
            min_id = ID

print("1: ID with least time:", min_id)
print("2: Avg transactino time (ms):", total_time / delta_count)
```